# Singleton in objective-c not reset when running unit tests

Tags: objective-c, unit-testing

In my application i have a singleton class. implemented like this:

```
@implementation PTKRGlobal
static PTKRGlobal *instance = nil;

+(PTKRGlobal *)shared
{
    @synchronized(self)
    {
        if(instance==nil)
        {
            instance= [PTKRGlobal new];
        }
    }
    return instance;
}
```

The header file of this class has all kinds of singleton properties like a codedatamanager:

```
@interface PTKRGlobal : NSObject
+(PTKRGlobal *)shared;
@property (strong, nonatomic) PTKRCoraDataManager *coreDataManger;
```

This allows me to call the manager using:

```
[[PTKRGlobal shared] coreDataManager]
```

in the appdeleget I set the manager:

```
[[PTKRGlobal shared] setCoreDataManger:[PTKRCoraDataManager new]];
```

When running unit test I have a subclassed PTKRCoreDataManager with some differences. When I however try to set the core data manager in the unit tests `[[PTKRGlobal shared] setCoreDataManger:[PTKRTestCoreDataManager new]];` I find that the variable is already set and does not allow to be reassigned. 
Presumable the PTKRGlobal is created during the running of what i believe is the functional tests run before the unit tests are ran. I verified this by putting a breakpoint at the app delegate and one at the unit test setUp and comparing the output os `po [[PTKRGlobal shared] coreDataManager]`

How can I reset this singleton before the start of the unittest?

Comment: Extract what you want to test to another class. Don not unit test singletons, that will make you life a lot easier! :-)

Answer (score 1):

Add a method to the class:

```
+ (void)destroySingleton {
    instance = nil;
}
```

And call it in the `tearDown` method of the unit test.

```
- (void)tearDown {
     [PTKRGlobal destroySingleton];
     [super tearDown];
}
```

---

As a note, you probably don't want to expose this publicly in your actual application, so just add this method in your `.m` file.

Then in the `.m` for your unit test, above the `@implementation` of the unit test, add the following:

```
@interface PTKRGlobal (UnitTesting)
+ (void)destroySingleton
@end
```

Comment: Does not seen to work. I verified that the singleton is destroyed by putting a breakpoint on `instance= [PTKRGlobal new];` after running `[PTKRGlobal destroySingleton];
    PTKRTestCoreDataManager *coreDataManager = [PTKRTestCoreDataManager new];
    [[PTKRGlobal shared] setCoreDataManger:coreDataManager];
`. I check the po [[PTKGlobal shared] coreDataManager] before and after destroy singleton and they are the same.

Comment: What do you mean "Does not seem to work" then?  You say you verified that the singleton is destroyed...

Comment: The singleton seems to be destroyed as a new one is created, however the coreDataManager seems the same before and after the singleton destruction

Comment: Your question is about resetting the singleton.  You provided code from the singleton.  If you want to ask about your code data manager, post a new question and ask about that.  As a hint, you should probably include code from your core data manager.

Comment: Sorry for being unclear: The problem is still with the reset. When I run `po [PTKRGlobal shared]` I get the same address before and after `[PTKRGlobal destroySingleton]`

Comment: That's because calling `shared` re-instantiates the object.  And it can reuse the same memory address.  Set a breakpoint in `shared` and see whether `instance` is `nil` after calling `destroySingleton` but before `if(instance==nil)`